# Data structure for efficient access of random slices of data from an API call

Tags: api, caching, data-structures

We are writing a library for an Api which pulls down on ordered stream of data. Through this Api you can make calls for data by slices. For instance if I want items 15-25 I can make an api call for that.

The library we are writing will allow the client to call for any slice of data as well, but we want the library to be as efficient with these api calls as possible. So if I've already asked for items 21-30, I don't want to ever request those individual data items again. If someone asks the library for 15-25 we want to call the api for 15-20. We will need to search for what data we already have and avoid requesting that data again.

What is the most efficient data structure for storing the results of these api calls? The data sets will not be huge so search time in local memory isn't that big of a deal. We are looking for simplicity and cleanliness of code. There are several obvious answers to this problem but I'm curious if any data structure nerds out there have an elegant solution that isn't coming to mind.

For reference we are coding in Python but are really just looking for a data structure that solves this problem elegantly.

Comment: When you say you don't ever want to request the data again, do you mean the individual items, e.g. 21, 22 ... 30, or do you mean the composite slice, e.g. 21-30? Or maybe both?

Comment: We want to be as efficient as possible with API calls so we never want to request those items again. If we already have 21-30 and someone calls for 15-25, we want to make a request for 15-20.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a balanced binary tree (e.g. http://pypi.python.org/pypi/bintrees/0.4.0) to map begin -> (end, data). When a new request comes in for [b, e) range, do a search for b (followed by move to previous record if b != key), another search for e (also step back), scan all entries between the resulting keys, pull down missing ranges, and merge all from-cache intervals and the new data into one interval. For N intervals in the cache, you'll get amortized O(log-N) cost of each cache update.

You can also simply keep a list of (begin, end, data) tuples, ordered by begin, and use bisect_right to search. Cost: O(N=number of cached intervals) for every update in the worst case, but if the clients tend to request data in increasing order, the cache update will be O(1).

Cache search itself is O(log-N) in either case.

Answer (score 0):

The canonical data structure often used to self this problem is an interval tree. (See [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree).) Your problem can be thought of as needing to know what things you've sent (what intervals) overlap with what you're trying to send -- then cut out the intervals that intersect with what you're trying to send (which is linear time with respect to the number of intervals that you find overlap) and you're there. The "Augmented" tree half way down the Wikipedia article looks simpler in implementation, though, so I'd stick with that. Should be "log N" time complexity, amortization or not.